# React. Ожидание ответа от сервера

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть компонент `User`, который рендерит компоненты `UserAuth` и `UserProfile`. Компонент `User` хранит `access_token`, который получает из `UserAuth`. Компонент `UserProfile` делает запрос к серверу (c `access_token``ом, который он взял из `User`), и отображает информацию про пользователя.

Проблема в том что дочерний компонент маунтится раньше родителя, поэтому при запросе к серверу в `componentDidMount()` компонент `UserProfile` еще не имеет `access_token`.

Как мне вызвать функцию запроса к серверу, когда `User` обновит свой стейт?

```
// User
class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      access_token: '',
    };
  }

  onUserChange = (new_user) => {
    this.setState(new_user);
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="User">
      <UserProfile accessToken={this.state.access_token} />
      <UserAuth userChange={this.onUserChange} />
    </div>
  }
}

// UserProfile
class UserProfile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      userProfile: 'No access token',
    }
  }

  // Где вызвать?
  updateUserProfile = async (request_params) => {
      //...Запрос к серверу...
      this.setState({userProfile: response});
  };

  render() {
      return <div className="UserProfile">
          {this.state.userProfile}
      </div>
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Не понятно, что такое `UserPage`, я предположу, что вы имели в виду `UserProfile`.
   Если это так, то зачем вам вообще показывать профиль пользователя до того, как у вас есть `access_token`? Просто не показывайте его до того, как токен будет получен от сервера

```
//....
{this.state.access_token &&<UserProfile accessToken={this.state.access_token} />}
//....
```

2. Зачем вам вообще `UserAuth`? Не было бы проще вынести его логику в `User`? Или вообще объединить с `UserProfile`? Судить, что лучше, сложно из-за того, что не ясна ваша композиция.
3. Ваш код не следует ни одному паттерну управления состоянием приложения в React, вся логика данных у вас находится в компонентах и нету глобального хранилища. А что, если вы захотите использовать `access_token` где-то еще? Также если ваш компонент сделает анмаунт с запущенным асинхронным методом, в конце которого выполняется `setState`, у вас будет ошибка.
   Я бы советовал забыть о подобном подходе в принципе. Изучите, что такое Redux и как вместе с ним писать асинхронные экшены (redux-saga, redux-thunk), либо используйте MobX - альтернатива Redux. Также может пригодиться Context, но он не такой гибкий, как остальные два, и не всегда применим.

И как примечание: вместо конструктора можно написать просто

```
class User extends React.Component {
 state = {
   access_token: '',
 }
//....
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, я действительно имел в виду `UserProfile`.
`access_token` я хотел использовать в компоненте `User` и передавать как props во все вложенные компоненты, где он нужен.
Я только начал изучать React и хотел написать что-то без Redux, но как я понял без него только больше проблем

Comment: Ну, смотря что вы хотели написать без него) Если todo-list, то можно и без него, но в большинстве случаев без него не обойтись, особенно когда есть что-то асинхронное

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать